# How to redirect all pages of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, redirect

Here's the deal. Let's say I have a custom post type called "subscriptions". Under this post type there are pages like the following:

- mysite.com/subscription/**my-first-subscription**
- mysite.com/subscription/**my-second-subscription**
- mysite.com/subscription/**my-third-subscription**

The issue is that I actually have a pricing page which allows users to use a widget to select the different subscriptions. I don't want the users to *ever* be able to access the subscription pages directly, even if they know the URL. My first thought is that I'd like any attempt to access a page of "subscription" type to be redirected to the pricing page. How would I do that?

(If someone has a better idea, I'm open to that as well.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by Milo it looks like it a duplicate of [How to disable the single view for a custom post type?]

```
<?php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'subscription_redirect_post' );

function subscription_redirect_post() {
  $queried_post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
  if ( is_single() && 'subscription' ==  $queried_post_type ) {
    wp_redirect( pricingpageURL, 301 );
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

Just swap our **pricingpageURL** with the pricing page URL value of your choice. Hope this helps.

Comment: How would I check to see if the subscription page contained a particular taxonomy? I'm not sure which variables are exposed at this point.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Looks like `get_the_id()` works, so I just used `has_term()`. Thanks!